# Can logical `and` be replaced by an if-statement and still have the same big-step semantics?

Tags: semantics, type-systems

In the system below can I replace all the `and t1 t2` substatements in some statement T (where T ⇓ v) with `if t1 then t2 else false` and still get the same result, meaning have T ⇓ v?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `and err false` reduces to `false` but `if err then false else false` gets stuck.

Comment: Is it possible to construct another kind of translation of the `and` term such that we can get rid of it and still have the same expressivity?